# git: rebase branch onto its rebased parent

Tags: git, rebase

The initial situation is very straightforward. Having a `feature_1` branch that is actively developed, and, branched from HEAD, a `feature_2` branch.

```
A-B: feature_1
   \ C: feature_2
```

Let's imagine commit A added a new file, commit B appended a line to that file and C appended another line. So the changes are all in one file and close to each other.

While working on feature_2, a new version of feature_1 is force pushed: `A-B': feature` where commit B was amended (for example to fix a typo).

I want to have this fix in branch feature_2 which I'm working on in parallel, so I rebase: `git checkout feature_2 && git rebase -i feature_1`. The goal is:

```
A-B': feature_1
   \ C': feature_2
```

The interactive (just to see what's happening behind the scenes) rebase menu gives me two commits to work with: B (the old one) and C.

First option: I just pick both of them. In this case there will be a conflict picking B and another conflict picking C. But basically it's the same conflict I have to resolve twice.

Second option: Having in this easy example the background knowledge that B is completely superseeded by B' which is already in feature_1 I can just drop B from the rebase menu and only have to resolve the conflict when rebasing C.

The second option works for such small fixes and a really small number of commits but imagine there was a big refactoring in feature_1 spanning over dozens of commits. The risk of dropping an important change by accident would be quite high.

Is there another way to limit the amout of conflict resolving I have to do here?

Comment: have you tried with a git merge?

Comment: I was under the impression that simply rebasing ``feature_2`` onto ``feature_1`` would work - i.e. ``git fetch`` then ``git rebase -i origin/feature_1``. Can you try that on a backup ``feature_2`` branch and see if it works?

Comment: @PenguinKnees You're absolutely right. The question is older than 6 months now and I can't remember if I was running into a specific problem back then. I just recreated a simple example and tried the rebase method: Works, but I have to resolve the conflict resulting from a small change potentially multiple times. That's the thing I'm unhappy with. I modified my question accordingly - hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you *know* that `B` was replaced by `B'`, the correct solution is to drop `B` from the rebase instruction sheet. Then you have to resolve only the conflict that arises when `C` is placed on top of `B'` (if any).

Note that there is no "risk of dropping an important change by accident" when you proceed in this way: if something was dropped, then only because `B` was morphed into `B'` by someone else (and there must have been a reason to do that).

If your upstream (`feature_1`) spans over more than one commit, then let's assume you have just fetched the new upstream with `git fetch`. Then you can do "the right thing" with

```
git checkout feature_2
git rebase --onto origin/feature_1 origin/feature_1@{1}
```

That is, you say that you want to transplant your feature branch on top of `origin/feature_1` (the new one), but you know that it branched off from the previous version (`@{1}`) of that branch.

Comment: Thanks for the solution which uses the revision syntax. Always interesting to learn new stuff about git.